# Can we customise the PDF file name generated by Orbeon?

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible to use parameters passed by service as the file name of the PDF generated by Orbeon?

If yes, what need to be done in `properties-local.xml`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no as of Orbeon Forms 4.8, but there is now an [RFE](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2122) implemented in Orbeon Forms 4.9.